# Equal width of sections on a dynamic width container?

Tags: dynamic, width, containers, equals

(html/css)

How do I set up a container of dynamic width, but each section in it has equal width so that they all resize at the same time with the container?

```
.container{
width:80%;
}
.section{
position:relative;
float:left;
width: 80%/6; <---- pseudo code
}
```

There are 6 equal sections. For example if the .container is 900px, then each .section would be 150px. If .container is 1200px, then each .section would be 200px.

Comment: You should at least specify a language.

Answer (score 0):

I started with web-development myself very recently. 
However, I hope this answer might help you.

```
 If your    class="section"    is within your     class="container"    , your browser will     
 assume that your    class="section"     width  is part of it's parent. It's parent is in    
 this case the        class="container".


 .container{
  width:80%;
  }   


 The     class="container"     width is based upon the width of it's parent. 
 The correct formula for this is: target/context=result

 Thus your    class="container"     width is in this case 80% and this based on the width      
 of the parent of your     class="container".

 Your     class="section"     width is inside your      class="container"    and is in     
 this case 80%, thus this width is based on it's parent width. 
 So your     class="container"     is now seen as 100% and your    class="section"     is 
 80% of your     class="container".
```

Hope this helps a bit.